# Overriding the Render method with a custom TextWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, overriding, web-controls

I would like to override the Render method of WebControl, however instead of HTMLTextWriter, I would like to use my HTMLTextWriterExtension class which inherits from HTMLTextWriter and has a few overrides in it with some functionality I need.

**Base Class Render** (WebControl)

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer);
```

**Override Class Render** (My Classes)

```
public override void Render(HtmlTextWriterExtension output)
```

The problem with the above is that this then isn't an override of the Render method, and so isn't called during the render.

I realise it's possible as WebControl has done the same thing as it overrides Control's render method with it's HTMLTextWriter.

I just can't work out how to do it. I'm probably having a mind dump, little bit ill and it's Monday morning.. This should be something easy.

Anyway, thanks for any advice you can give me. 
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the same signature, then use your writer, then copy content from your writer to original writer:

Base Class Render (WebControl)

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer);
```

Override Class Render (My Classes)

```
public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    // string builder is just an example of storage that custom TextWriter uses
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var myCustomWriter = new HtmlTextWriterExtension(builder);
    base.Render(myCustomWriter);
    myCustomWriter.Flush();

    // write content written from base class to original writer
    output.Write(builder.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry yes, I've made a mistake, I thought Control was using TextWriter, but it is in fact HTMLTextWriter. This had led me to believe there was an alternative way. Thanks for your help!